# console.log(); that goes in <p>?

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

I have a little program where you have a list of ice cream flavors and the computer use "console.log();" to print a sentence and the flavour. I have started the project and it looks like this:

```
var randomFlavour = Math.random() * 10;

    if (randomFlavour < 1) {
    var randomFlavour = "chocolate";
} else if (randomFlavour < 2) {
    var randomFlavour = "vanilla";
} else if (randomFlavour < 3) {
    var randomFlavour = "pistachio";
} else if (randomFlavour < 4) {
    var randomFlavour = "strawberry";
} else if (randomFlavour < 5) {
    var randomFlavour = "cotton candy";
} else if (randomFlavour < 6) {
    var randomFlavour = "cookie dough";
} else if (randomFlavour < 7) {
    var randomFlavour = "bubblegum";
} else if (randomFlavour < 8) {
    var randomFlavour = "peanut butter";
} else if (randomFlavour < 9) {
    var randomFlavour = "mint";
} else {
    var randomFlavour = "gingerbread man";
}

console.log("Hello. I would like to have" + " " + randomFlavour + " " + "ice cream please.");
```

The problem is; this will just print in the console, and I want the text printed to transform in `<p>` paragraphs, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to access your `<p>` element.

You will need to asssign an id to your element:

```
<p id="myPar">
</p>
```

Then you can get in in js like so:

```
var par = document.getElementById('myPar');
```

Then to set its text, you can use `innerHTML`

```
par.innerHTML  = randomFlavour;
```

Comment: That worked better than the first answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Create `<p></p>` element, edit it's `innerHTML`, add to the `DOM` :

```
var par = document.createElement('p')
par.innerHTML = "Hello. I would like to have " + randomFlavour + " ice cream please."
document.body.appendChild(par)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `console.log();` you could use,

```
document.getElementById("idhere").innerHTML = "your string here";
```

for "idhere" put the id of the paragraph you want to change.

Answer (score -1):

On the same level you wrote the console.log() do a document.write(); with the output. console.log only outputs to the console whereas document.write writes to your html page.

Comment: No, document.write will obliterate the entire document. This is bad practice.

Comment: invoke it while the page is still being parsed

Comment: given his code, i'm giving him the most generic basic example. There is nothing wrong with that, the code assumes this is all the page is doing. Obviously if he wants to put it somewhere like inside of a div he can do that the proper way, but i'm assuming he's not a moron...

Comment: @guest Why don't you add that to your own answer?

Comment: hell naw, I ain't falling for that. just look at what happens to an answer that dares mention `document.write`!